# Output of piped command to variable not working

Tags: sed, pipe, variable

When I try the following there is no problem:

```
$ date '+%y%m' | sed 's/.\(.*\)/\1/'
906
```

But When I try to store it in a variable it seems nothing is stored:

```
$ dd=`date '+%y%m' | sed 's/.\(.*\)/\1/'`
$ echo "$dd"
```

I know I can get the same result by not using `sed`:

```
$ dd=`date '+%y%m'`
$ echo ${dd: -3}
906
```

but I'm curious why it doesn't work with `sed`.

Comment: It seems to work fine. Which shell are you using

Comment: I'm using git-bash for Windows.

Comment: It is working on the git-bash also! are you printing the right variable name?

Comment: Yes. Pretty sure!

Comment: Prefer dd=$( ... ) syntax instead of dd=` ... `

Comment: @FedonKadifeli That doesn't work either. Weird!

Comment: @Inian Apparently there are different variants of Git for windows ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672272/msysgit-vs-git-for-windows)). I'm using `MinGW` variant.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use commands as a variable name. `dd` is your disc destroyer, look at `man dd` and try another variable name or something like this:

```
d=`date '+%y%m' | sed 's/.\(.*\)/\1/'`
echo $d
```

Maybe this part of the `bash` manual is also usefull:

```
man bash | sed -n '/^DEFINITIONS/,/^SHELL GRAMMAR/p' | less
```